# pharo smalltalk Window closing

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am using Pharo Smalltalk version 4.0 to build a simple GUI app. I wish to make sure that "StandardWindow" that I have created does not close when the user clicks on the "X" button in the top corner. Hence, I am sending the message "mustNotClose" to my window object, which is an instance variable of the superclass SystemWindow. However, the window still closes when I click on the "X" button. Any ideas about what am I missing? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `mustNotClose` is only an accessor for checking that the instance variable `mustNotClose` is set to true:

```
mustNotClose
    ^ mustNotClose == true
```

You should use the method `makeUnclosable` that actually deletes the close button. You can then add the close button back using `makeClosable`.

Comment: You are right, that worked. Thanks much, I appreciate it.